# During make mupdf, fatal error: X11/Xlib.h file not found in mac

Tags: c, macos, mupdf

I am installing muPDF.

I gave an input like `make prefix=/usr/local install` in terminal

I have installed XQuartz already

But I get an error as follows

```
In file included from thirdparty/glfw/src/context.c:28:
In file included from thirdparty/glfw/src/internal.h:85:
thirdparty/glfw/src/x11_platform.h:35:10: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
     ^
```

Comment: Did you search for a solution before posting?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I don't complete from theis solution

Answer (score 4):

```
  make XCFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include XLIBS=-L/opt/X11/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Mac OS X 10.9;

The makefile looks for **X11** headers into `/usr/local/include/X11` instead of `/opt/X11/include/X11`

The quick fix is a symlink

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/local/include/X11
```

You may also need this further fix for OpenGL headers

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/X11/include/GL /usr/local/include/GL
```

Probably exists a more elegant solution by specifying headers location when invoking `make` but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: Like adding -I/opt/X11/include/ to one of the CFLAGS or similar variables ... I'd expect to need a similar -L flag added to LDFLAGS or LIBS variables.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for now is to use the X11 mupdf (and disable the openGL one):

```
make HAVE_GLFW=no
```